# H264 Video in DOTNETNUKE

Tags: dotnetnuke

We are about to add h264 video to our website.  So far it looks like we are going to use [Ultra Video Gallery 3 Professional Edition](http://bizmodules.net/).

What are the good alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Ultra Gallery 3 should work great if you don't intend to do much customization of the video controls.